# Why can not I get the locale from header object in expression language, jsp?

Tags: jsp, http, el

Here is my code:

```
${header}
<br />
Locale is: ${header.locale}
```

And here is the output:

> {cookie=JSESSIONID=F2E1140376438A2D79BCD2FC23D97574; locale=en,
>   cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive,
>   accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.6, host=localhost:8080,
>   .... much more data here... }
>
> Locale is:

So clearly locale exists in the **header** but why **header.locale** does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
${pageContext.response.locale}
```

Or try

```
${pageContext.request.locale.language}
```

Or try

```
${header['accept-language']}
```

Comment: locale is part of request and response. Read from cookie you might get the same value. check this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_cookies_handling.htm)